# How to get the ID of parent Node on checkbox checked in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to get the ID of parent Node(collapse1) on checkbox checked in jquery.

```
   <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1" 
   style="height: auto;">
  <div class="panel-body">
         <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="option-input checkbox" name="filter[]" value="1" checked="checked"> <span class="ml-10">Core i5 (25)</span>

             </label>
    </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
           <label>         
         <input type="checkbox" class="option-input checkbox" name="filter[]" value="2"> <span 
         class="ml-10">Core i7 (18)</span>
           </label>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I tried the following code but not able to get

```
var pid = this.parentNode.id;
```

Comment: you mean `collapse1` ?  if yes then use `$(this).closest('.panel-collapse').attr('id')`

Comment: It worked thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use checkbox `:checked` property for this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').closest('.panel-collapse').attr('id');
```

Working snippet:

```js
console.log($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').closest('.panel-collapse').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1" 
   style="height: auto;">
  <div class="panel-body">
         <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="option-input checkbox" name="filter[]" value="1" checked="checked"> <span class="ml-10">Core i5 (25)</span>

             </label>
    </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
           <label>         
         <input type="checkbox" class="option-input checkbox" name="filter[]" value="2"> <span 
         class="ml-10">Core i7 (18)</span>
           </label>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

***Note:*** As I am unable to see `this` related stuff in your question code, That's why I have given you above solution.

Incase `this` related stuff available (As you are saying), then you can go with ***@Swati*** code directly:

```
$(this).closest('.panel-collapse').attr('id')
```